# Is there a way to regulate the JavaScript array.find output to certain "categories" in a 2D-Array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have following 2D-Array...

```
let calendar = [
        {date: "1/1",   emoji: "",    title: "New Year"},
        {date: "24/1",  emoji: "",    title: "International Day of Education"},
        {date: "11/2",  emoji: "",    title: "International Day of Women and Girls in Science"},
    ];
```

and some variables:

```
var date
```

which represents the current date in a "day/month" format.

```
var emoji
var title
```

which represent the fitting emoji and the title of the day.

I now have the date (for example "1/1") and want to search for it in the array.

Normally, there would be an output like this:  *date : "1/1",   emoji: "",    title: "New Year"*. It would just take the whole object. But because I want to take the output and take it as a value for my variables: *emoji* & *title*, I need to regulate the output, so that I search for the date in the array and find a value for the *emoji variable* (expected value: ) and for the *title variable*. (expected value: New Year)

Comment: Something like `calendar.find(obj => obj.date==="1/1").emoji` ?

Comment: or `const {title, emoji} = calendar.find(obj => obj.date==="1/1")`? Your use of the term "regulate" is a bit confusing

Answer (score 0):

You can use javascript's Array.filter-method for that:

```js
let calendar = [
    {date: "1/1",   emoji: "",    title: "New Year"},
    {date: "24/1",  emoji: "",    title: "International Day of Education"},
    {date: "11/2",  emoji: "",    title: "International Day of Women and Girls in Science"},
]

let filtered = calendar.filter(el => {
  return el.date === '1/1'
})

filtered.forEach(el => {
  console.log(el.emoji,el.title)
})
```

Be aware: Array.filter returns a new Array including all matched elements!
If you only need the first matching element's content you should use Array.filter:

```js
let calendar = [
    {date: "1/1",   emoji: "",    title: "New Year"},
    {date: "24/1",  emoji: "",    title: "International Day of Education"},
    {date: "11/2",  emoji: "",    title: "International Day of Women and Girls in Science"},
]

let found = calendar.find(el => {
  return el.date === '1/1'
})

console.log(found.emoji, found.title)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
let date = '1/1'
let {emoji, title} = calendar.filter(item => item.date === date)[0]
```

but not clearly understandeble what you realy want. What problem to take needed fields from resulting object?